# CSS overflow auto not scrolling smoothly for position fixed on iphone

Tags: javascript, css

I have a button that you click on and a div appears.
If you'll scroll down from an iPhone you'll see that it's not scrolling smoothly as it should. for some reason it's losing that behavior and I don't know why.

**HTML**

```
<button id="page1">Hey</button>

    <div class="page1">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero sunt nemo, unde, nisi quisquam minus blanditiis rerum harum obcaecati, dolore perspiciatis? Ad nemo aperiam cumque a delectus facilis tempora architecto?</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui laboriosam minus praesentium excepturi cumque culpa quibusdam, maiores odit cupiditate natus, possimus, libero repellendus sed doloribus animi eos cum dolorum at.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis et hic tenetur velit iste dignissimos est suscipit ducimus facilis, quibusdam dicta iure quidem beatae quisquam sit quasi harum, provident nostrum at illum. Quisquam accusamus autem id dolorem harum aspernatur est impedit amet, asperiores praesentium, vitae molestiae repellendus natus velit libero ipsam, qui assumenda pariatur nulla dicta ea voluptatum. Dolorem eos officia, et nostrum numquam quasi hic corrupti fugit commodi beatae aliquid minima, vel dolores maiores ex! Quas soluta nemo quod, natus quo tenetur odio, repellendus iure amet fuga! Odit temporibus debitis voluptate blanditiis, veniam delectus minima dolores, commodi quas laborum nobis dolorem placeat ea, officia magnam totam fuga corporis cumque. Quos asperiores veritatis quo! Quo dolorum officiis temporibus repudiandae aliquam esse, ex expedita sed sequi corporis voluptatum ullam accusamus laboriosam quae, ducimus ea qui quia! Quis nostrum, distinctio maxime. Similique in assumenda ipsum officia incidunt rem ratione velit harum dolore labore id aperiam quaerat magnam iste ipsam, minima, rerum consequuntur earum modi molestiae dolorum optio temporibus! Adipisci optio ex, fugiat nostrum sint, sunt at. Reprehenderit autem mollitia earum, ipsa porro, tempora tenetur impedit omnis unde iure, alias vitae illo quod ab assumenda magnam molestias atque provident voluptatem laboriosam quae! Optio quisquam corporis beatae iure, natus, cumque porro, ullam dolorem illum odit quia itaque ut molestias voluptas. Architecto animi ratione, ad accusamus commodi fugit nemo laborum similique illum suscipit deleniti, sed deserunt? Quis nam quasi qui ab vel dignissimos vitae in, aspernatur soluta aliquam explicabo magni alias tempore, molestias facilis ducimus aut inventore neque animi hic. Soluta officiis exercitationem iure magnam earum facere provident, alias delectus explicabo quibusdam tempora amet aperiam, unde, vitae! Dolorem neque, commodi harum libero officiis explicabo perspiciatis ullam. Quisquam, nostrum illo cum hic eaque! Iste ut omnis ab accusantium eaque quaerat dolorum, nulla eius rerum est ipsa. Nostrum asperiores esse porro nam, sint minus ullam. Enim porro eveniet harum, ducimus veritatis eius natus non quo eaque ut repudiandae hic sunt dolores quibusdam maxime fugiat fugit distinctio! Inventore alias commodi perferendis minus sint ipsum officia quaerat aperiam sapiente in ratione, accusantium nobis eum et temporibus cum accusamus consectetur doloribus illum? Odio quisquam placeat deleniti. Ducimus accusantium at esse autem architecto incidunt omnis earum, ipsam dignissimos, dolorem ex quibusdam! Repellendus expedita unde, ullam, placeat, aut officia doloremque mollitia impedit quidem sequi maxime. Cumque sit eaque repellendus perferendis, accusamus deserunt iusto error quod magni, quo vero unde molestiae corporis suscipit?</p>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.page1 { 
    display:none;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    overflow:auto;
    background:#039;
    color:#fff;
    padding:40px;
 }
.noscrolling {
    overflow:hidden;
}
button {
    margin:30px;
}
```

**JS**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){

            $('button').click(function(){
                var button_id = $(this).attr('id');
                $('.'+button_id).fadeIn();
                $('body').addClass('noscrolling');
            });

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-overflow-scrolling

Comment: `overflow: scroll;` for enabling scroll

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this css.

```
.page1 {
  overflow-y: scroll; /* has to be scroll, not auto */
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```